# The symbol $(Y-Y_1)^-$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry* and on p. 5, in the proof of Proposition 1.5, there suddenly appeared the symbol $Z=(Y-Y_1)^-$ in the second paragraph. What does the symbol mean? This is supposed to make $Z=Y_2\cup\cdots\cup Y_r$ hold.

Comment: The closure of $Y-Y_1$ perhaps?

Comment: Why then, is $Z=Y_2\cup\cdots\cup Y_r$ true?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is $A^-$ in topology?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46853/what-is-a-in-topology)